# Ограничение доступа по $http_user_agent в Nginx

Tags: php, c#, nginx

Есть приложение, которое по HTTP протоколу подключается к Web сайту и получает от PHP скриптов информацию или статический файл. Стоит задача ограничить доступ через функционал `Nginx` к сайту по полю `User-Agent`. Беда в том, что в интернетах я не нашёл адекватного описания как формируется это самое правило для моего случая.

В моём случает строка состоит из следующего значение (не статическое) - **MyAppWebKit x.x.x.x**. Где **x.x.x.x** - версия клиента. Она меняется в зависимости от билда приложения.

Код который я в данный момент использую в `Nginx` работает, но рубит всё:

```
if ($http_user_agent != MyAppWebKit) {
    return 403;
}
```

Код в приложении для доступа к сайту:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers["User-Agent"] = "MyAppWebKit " + Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
    client.Headers["Public-Key"] = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    client.Headers["System-Locale"] = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;

    return client.DownloadString(url).Length > 0;
}
```

Подскажите как правильно составить правило для моего случая или где популярно, на бытовом языке, это расписано.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код:

```
client.Headers["User-Agent"] = "MyAppWebKit " + Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
```

сделает вам `User-Agent` равный "MyAppWebKit Х.Х.Х.Х", так?

Далее.

```
if ($http_user_agent != MyAppWebKit) {
    return 403;
}
```

тут "строгое" неравенство на MyAppWebKit, т.е.:

```
if ("MyAppWebKit Х.Х.Х.Х" != MyAppWebKit) {
    return 403;
}
```

не равно?
не равно! значит `return 403;`

Поэтому надо либо так:

```
if ($http_user_agent != "MyAppWebKit X.X.X.X") {
    return 403;
}
```

Либо так:

```
if ($http_user_agent !~ MyAppWebKit) {
        return 403;
}
```

Comment: Это всё хорошо. А есть возможность задать условие проверки вхождения подстроки в строку `User-Agent`? Например, если этот параметр начинается с **MyAppWebKit** то разрешать доступ. Мне `User-Agent` и в скриптах сайта нужен и именно версия билда. Я думал, что уже на стороне `Nginx` можно отсеять ненужные клиенты. А так, это я всё читал и пробовал до написания вопроса.

Comment: @Rootware `вхождение подстроки в строку` и `параметр начинается с` - это разные условия поиска. Ставьте полное регулярное выражение под свой юзер-агент `^MyAppWebKit\s\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+` и будет вам щастье.

Comment: Извиняюсь за неточное определение. В PHP привык так проверять наличие подстроки в строке через первое вхождение. Отсюда местами непонятные определения. Кстати только заметил в последнем куске кода сравнение. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Сам спросил - сам ответил.

Руководствуясь иной [проблемой](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?21,264075,264075#msg-264075) с официального форума нашёл верное решение для своей задачи. Выглядит это, как оказалось, тривиально. Вот только синтаксис никто не объяснил.

```
if ($http_user_agent !~* "(MyAppWebKit)") {
    return 403;
}
```

Все агенты имеющие подстроку `MyAppWebKit` в `User-Agent` пропускаются, остальным отдаётся 403-й код.

Comment: и чем это отличается от `if ($http_user_agent !~ MyAppWebKit) {
        return 403;
}` кроме case insensitive модификатора?

Comment: Тем что `User-Agent` вида `MyAppWebKit 1.0.1.1` пропускается. А вашем случае требуется точное соответствие.